# How can I rewrite HTML replacing the parent tag that is the same tag as the children?

Tags: jquery, html, cheerio

I'm reading from API a bunch of html content

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        content: '{html...}'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        content: '{html...}'
    }
]
```

After get this data, I do some replacements using [sanitize-html](https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html). But now I have to do some extra work.

Sometimes I get this

```
<p>some text...<p>
<p>
    <p>some text...<p>
    <p>
        <img />
        <span>some text</span>
    <p>
<p>
```

or this

```
<p>some text...<p>
<p>some text...<p>
<p>
    <img />
    <span>some text</span>
<p>
```

What I pretend to do, it's keep my paragraphs in one level, so I thought to use [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) (which uses jQuery core), doing something like

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(content);
content = $('p:not(:has(>p))').html();
```

But this will bring only the first `p` and only when exists. And if I do get the others manually, I may lost the right order of the content.

So, is there a good way to clean the HTML keeping only one level of `p` according my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid.

- A `p` element may not contain a `p` element
- The end tag for `p` is optional
- Attempting to put a `p` inside another `p` will implicitly close the first `p`
- The extra end tags will be ignored

This program:

```
const content = `

<p>some text...<p>
<p>
    <p>some text...<p>
    <p>
        <img />
        <span>some text</span>
    <p>
<p>


`;

const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(content);
console.log($.html());
```

will output this:

```
<html><head></head><body><p>some text...</p><p>
</p><p>
    </p><p>some text...</p><p>
    </p><p>
        <img>
        <span>some text</span>
    </p><p>
</p><p>


</p></body></html>
```

So just calling `$.html()` will flatten the paragraph nesting.

Comment: At the first try, I thought that didn't work, but a sip of coffee made me see clearly. Thank you.